# vb.net Program not launching correctly on new thread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I'm working on a program that will need to start other programs on occasion. The programs it would start are all custom, so there's no IOP class to reference.

There is a theoretical possibility of needing to run multiple programs simultaneously, so I'm attempting to put each program I start on it's own thread. This is my first attempt at multithreading, so I'm pretty certain I'm failing there somehow, but I'm not sure where.

To start the program I use the following code

```
Try
    Dim nt As New ExecThreadObj

    'Fill in the properties
    nt.Status = "Running"
    nt.TaskName = spo.Name
    nt.prog = spo.Prog
    nt.STime = Now
    nt.T = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf nt.StartProgram)
    nt.T.Start()

    'Add to the running list
    TList.Add(nt)
    Running.Add(spo.Name)
Catch ex As Exception
    EL.AddErr("Encountered an error while trying to start a thread for " & spo.Name & ". Error Details: " & ex.Message, EPath)
End Try
```

I never enter the catch block so there's no outright error, but the form for the program I'm using to test never shows up either. For context here is `nt.StartProgram`

```
Public Function StartProgram() As String
    '
    Dim ret As String = ""

    Try
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(prog)
    Catch ex As Exception
        ret = "Failed to start the program " & TaskName & " due to the following error: " & ex.Message
    End Try

    Return ret
End Function
```

I also never enter the Catch block here. As a last check, I hardcoded creating and filling in `nt`, rather than populating it from memory, and then attempted to start it programmatically. This did work, the code follows

```
Private Sub TestForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
    '
    'TM.MF = Me
    'TM.Main()    NOTE: this runs the code that I referred to above that doesn't seem to work

    Dim nt As New ExecThreadObj

    'Fill in the properties
    nt.Status = "Running"
    nt.TaskName = "Test"
    nt.prog = "C:\FullPathIWontShare.exe"
    nt.STime = Now
    nt.T = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf nt.StartProgram)
    nt.T.Start()
End Sub
```

Just for full disclosure, here's the entirety of TM.Main

```
Public Sub Main()
    '
    Dim w As Integer = 3000 '500

    'Load the schedule
    If System.IO.File.Exists(SPath) Then
        'Create a backup copy
        System.IO.File.Copy(SPath, Replace(SPath, ".xml", "_backup.xml"))

        'Load the data
        X.FromXML(Sched, SPath, "Task Runner-Load", EPath)

        'Run the actual program
        Do While cont
            ThreadCheck()

            'Update the form
            MF.ListView1.Items.Clear()
            For Each t As ExecThreadObj In TList
                Dim temp(2) As String
                temp = {t.TaskName, t.STime}
                Dim NLI As New ListViewItem(temp)
                MF.ListView1.Items.Add(NLI)
            Next
            MF.Refresh()

            'Wait the proscribed period
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(w)
        Loop
    End If 'else there's nothing to run
End Sub
```

ThreadCheck has methods for starting and cleaning up the threads I'll be using. The issue is in StartThread() so I'll show that as well

```
Public Sub StartThreads()
    '
    Dim c As Boolean = True

    'Check the current thread count
    Dim TC As Integer = TList.Count

    'Can we start anything?
    If TC < 5 Then
        'Start threads for new tasks from the schedule (if there is space)
        For Each spo As ComObjLib.SchedProgObj In Sched
            If TList.Count < 5 Then
                If spo.NextRun.AddDays(spo.RT) <= Now And Not (Running.Contains(spo.Name)) Then
                    'The program should start, so do so
                    Try
                        Dim nt As New ExecThreadObj

                        'Fill in the properties
                        nt.Status = "Running"
                        nt.TaskName = spo.Name
                        nt.prog = spo.Prog
                        nt.STime = Now
                        nt.T = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf nt.StartProgram)

                        'Add to the running list
                        TList.Add(nt)
                        Running.Add(spo.Name)
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        EL.AddErr("Encountered an error while trying to start a thread for " & spo.Name & ". Error Details: " & ex.Message, EPath)
                    End Try
                End If 'else we don't need to do anything
            Else
                'do nothing for now, the task will have to wait
            End If
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

Thanks!